# Linking two tables in sql for dynamic data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables, one containing user information (name, address, postcode, email etc) and the other containing user preferences (style of house, size of house, value of house, etc).

The first tables information is inputted on a certain webpage, and the data is inserted into the table with no issues upon pressing the submit button. I have a hidden auto-incrementing column for the unique id of that user. I then did exactly the same for the second table on a second form on the next webpage.

How can I ensure that the id column in the first table always matches the id in the second column? If a user was to complete the first webpage and submit the information, but then not complete the second page, there would be a discrepancy in the two unique id's and the two sets of data would no longer match up for future users of the site.

Im sure there is a very easy way to link the two tables depending on the user at that time but as im new to this language and databasing im having trouble figuring it out!!

(If it helps, im using Dreamweaver with PHP coding on the website to link to the sql server, with a local server set up using XAMPP.)

Comment: Don't use an auto-incrementer, just use the user's ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Im sure there is a very easy way to link the two tables depending on the user

The best way of linking users between tables is to use an identifier for that user (let's call it a user ID). Generate an ID for the user when they complete the first table. Next when they move on to complete more details about the property, recall the ID generated for the user and submit that.

Comment: so how do i pass the initial unique id from the first table to the second table? Im presuming I drag the id from the first table in code on the second webpage, and then put that in the second table? but how do i ensure it is the same users id (i cant just access the latest row of data in case there are two users simultaneously) Another way ive thought of but dismissed is passing a variable from the first webpage to the second but the unique id isnt created untill the form is submitted, correct?

Comment: You need to track the session that the user has created. In PHP this is done with `session_start()` which creates a cookie on the user's computer. It is generated for the new user when they open the first page. You can store the generated user ID in the $_SESSION variable after creating it from the first table, then access it for accepting the post of the second table data (don't send it to the browser and expect it back - the user could modify it which would present a security issue).

Comment: ok thanks for your help - ill look into cookies (there seems to be a very steep learning curve for web design - ive done app design in the past and so have got quite proficient at iOS, but web design is alot more than just one language, its a menagerie of many different languages working together!!)

Answer (score 0):

use table structure like this:

```
user (unique_autoincrement_id, other_fields)
user_properties (unique_autoincrement_id, user_id_linked_to_user_table, other_fields)
```

do NOT use two different autoincrement fields to identify one user - you definitely will have big and nasty issues with it.

Answer (score 0):

When a user submit some data that goes saved somewhere in a table in your database, you may want to have a column like "user_id" that contains the id of the user that have generated the row.

Plus you may want to search on google for "foreign key" and "inner join".